# error operator expected in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written code to display all the box positions of a square, like if a user enters 4, the square has the size 4x4 and all its positions have to be printed. I have written the prolog program for that, but I am getting operator expected error....
Here is my code:

```
printsqpos(N):- printnum(1,N).

printnum(I,NUM):- I<=NUM,printrow(I,NUM),N1 is I+1,printnum(N1,NUM).

printrow(I,N):- printcell(I,1,N).

printcell(I,J,N):- J<=N,write(I,J),K is J+1,printcell(I,K,N).
```

I am new to prolog and practising the thing...  Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the error is: `..., J <= M, ...`  write `..., J =< M, ...` instead.

In Prolog less-than-or-equal is written `=<`. That might look odd at first. But a frequent use of Prolog is to implement theorem provers. There, `<=` is rather seen as an right-to-left arrow and not a comparison operator.

But there is more: Take `printnum/2` which consists of a single recursive rule. That means that this predicate will **never** succeed. It might fail or loop.

Comment: yes your answer is perfect.... I don't know why would i got negative rating with this.... I have just started to learn porlog..... so these doubts are obvious

Comment: @JatinKhurana: You are right. My point was only that it will *never* succeed - and usually one expects that a predicate will succeed.

Comment: @JatinKhurana: w.r.t. votes: best get the "Informed" badge to see how votes are seen here.